# Why aren't respondents from a Google form getting added to a Google Calendar event using Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to get an app script to automatically add guests to a google calendar event once they filled in a form.

**Here is my app script code:**

function addGuest(event) {

let email = event.values[1];
let sendinvite = event.values[7]

if(sendinvite === 'Main Campus') {

```
let Maincampusevent = CalendarApp. getEventsForDay(new Date(2023,6,6),{search: 'Staff Forum & 25th Anniversary Tea'});

Maincampusevent[0].addGuest(email);
```

} else { return }

}

**Attached is the spreadsheet where the form responses are collected**

[spreadsheet where the form responses are collected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MdL5E.png)**

**Here are the Google Calendar Event Details:**

Event Name: Staff Forum & 25th Anniversary Tea Reception for Staff

Event Date: 6 Jul 2023
Event Time: 1pm

**Trigger Settings:**

Choose which function to run: addGuest
Which runs at deployment: Head
Select event source: From spreadsheet
Select event type: On form Submit
Failure notification settings: Notify me immediately

The trigger runs successfully but the respondent isn't added to the calendar invite.